# Compare and print the values with python dataframe elements

Tags: python, pandas

This is a program in which I have calculated the confidence intervals and then I am trying to compare the dataframe values and trying to print the records which are within the upper and lower limit.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/amuly/Desktop/Student_Weight_Status_Category_Reporting_Results__Beginning_2010.csv')


#confidence interval for number of obese
margin=df["NO. OBESE"].sem()*1.96
upper_limit=df["NO. OBESE"].mean()+margin
lower_limit=df["NO. OBESE"].mean()-margin
print(lower_limit,upper_limit)
```

I am getting the correct outputs till here...

Next I am trying to have only those values which are within my confidence interval

The error is- The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
if (df["NO. OBESE"]>=lower_limit) & (df["NO. OBESE"]<=upper_limit):
    correlate_data=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I am new to pandas.Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[(df["NO. OBESE"]>=lower_limit) & (df["NO. OBESE"]<=upper_limit)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much